# Tabs magically converted to two spaces when rebasing

Tags: git, pbxproj

When I'm rebasing my branch, I get a merge-conflict even though I both sources has tab-indented content (for my `project.pbxproj` in Xcode).

Ok, so, I'm here:

```
$ git st
rebase in progress; onto b54f22f
You are currently rebasing branch 'feature' on 'b54f22f'.
```

What I rebase onto:

```
$ git show master:MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj | head -n 5 | xxd
00000000: 2f2f 2021 242a 5554 4638 2a24 210a 7b0a  // !$*UTF8*$!.{.
00000010: 0961 7263 6869 7665 5665 7273 696f 6e20  .archiveVersion 
00000020: 3d20 313b 0a09 636c 6173 7365 7320 3d20  = 1;..classes = 
00000030: 7b0a 097d 3b0a                           {..};.
```

(see that `archiveVersion` is tab-indented, ascii `09`)

What is being rebased:

(applied second, introduces the indention-problem)

```
$ git show 480cc3fff4b36f00f617277653517362f567aaf5:MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj | head -n 5 | xxd
00000000: 2f2f 2021 242a 5554 4638 2a24 210a 7b0a  // !$*UTF8*$!.{.
00000010: 0961 7263 6869 7665 5665 7273 696f 6e20  .archiveVersion 
00000020: 3d20 313b 0a09 636c 6173 7365 7320 3d20  = 1;..classes = 
00000030: 7b0a 097d 3b0a
```

(applied first)

```
$ git show ffafa60d714c94c7d7722e4f63aa08572f808f28:MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj | head -n 5 | xxd
00000000: 2f2f 2021 242a 5554 4638 2a24 210a 7b0a  // !$*UTF8*$!.{.
00000010: 0961 7263 6869 7665 5665 7273 696f 6e20  .archiveVersion 
00000020: 3d20 313b 0a09 636c 6173 7365 7320 3d20  = 1;..classes = 
00000030: 7b0a 097d 3b0a
```

See, all version contains ascii `09` and no spaces (ascii `20`).

What could the problem be?

Here's the structure of the branches when rebasing:

[image]

As requested by someone:

```
$ git config --global apply.whitespace
$ git config apply.whitespace
$

(no output)
```

Comment: Try running `git config --global apply.whitespace` and `git config apply.whitespace`. What do you get back?

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio Nothing, empty